# prevent removing new lines from base64 string c#

Tags: c#, android, base64

I'm trying to simulate the android `Base64.encode` in C#. But when I compared the results, I realized they are different. Android result has a `/n` at the end of string but my result doesn't have that:

```
Android Result: "gqo+8pdjV2VGRr2Ap5fzVzZTd2Q\n" 
C# Result:      "gqo+8pdjV2VGRr2Ap5fzVzZTd2Q="
```

How can I prevent removing new lines from base64 string in C#?

I used simple base64 convert in C# like this:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(data)
```

and the android code is this:

```
Base64.encodeToString(data,1)
```

Comment: Just add that newline yourself? I cannot imagine though why a method to convert binary data to base64 would append unrelated characters to the output... I mean it's not C# removing anything - it's android function adding them.

Comment: I don't see an overload in Android without flags? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64#encodeToString(byte[],%20int)

Comment: i cant add it my self. i don't know when i should i add new line to the end of string. its not happening all the time.

Comment: Do you want to corrupt the base64 string?  You can't modify the stringif you want to be able to convert back to the string.

Comment: You can make C# add linebreaks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.base64formattingoptions?view=netcore-3.1 using [ToBase64String(Byte[], Base64FormattingOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToBase64String_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Base64FormattingOptions_)

Comment: thanks dear @Fildor. the flag is 0. i forgot to mention it.

Comment: @jdweng. i don't want to corrupt anything. i just want to have android base 64 in c#.

Comment: Can you just make android side to not emit those newlines (with mentioned flags)?

Comment: @Evk _"why a method to convert binary data to base64 would append unrelated characters to the output"_ : _"The encoded output stream must be represented **in lines of no more  than 76 characters each**.  All line breaks or other characters not
   found in Table 1 must be ignored by decoding software."_ - [RFC2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) p.24 (emphasis by me) - just learned that, too :))

Comment: thanks @Evk. but i cant change android side.

Comment: The c# library says following for the method frobase64string :System.FormatException: The length of s, ignoring white-space characters, is not zero or a multiple of 4. -or-The format of s is invalid. s contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters.

Comment: @Fildor but mentioned string is not even 76 characters, and even if it was - encoding for email message by _default_? Doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: @Evk I agree with you. Nevertheless the RFC states a ... well not really a "reason" ... but at least why "a method to convert binary data to base64 would append unrelated characters to the output" (a method that is compliant with said RFC, I'd say) ... What Android is doing here goes beyond me, though. Especially when OP states _"its not happening all the time"_ ...

Comment: @jdweng `\n` is considered "white-space" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: BTW, I came up with RFC 2045 in the first place, because Android docs say about the flags in Base64.encodeToString: _" Passing DEFAULT results in output that adheres to RFC 2045."_

Comment: The size of the string has to be a multiple of 4 and can contain one or two additional white space padding characters.  So the return characters should be ignored by c#.

Comment: This is a linux (or java)  issue.  It looks like java method has all the RFC options so you can generate all the RFC allowable outputs and then test that you decode method works with all the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android appends `\n` character, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64

You can either remove linebreakes in Android by using the following flag https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64#NO_WRAP

```java
Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

C# encodes the data by using following flags https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.base64formattingoptions?view=netcore-3.1#fields

```cs
Convert.ToBase64String(data, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
```

however the `InsertLineBreaks` flags adds the `\n` character after every 76 characters, which does not look like your case.

Comment: thsnks. but acording to the document Inserts line breaks after every 76 characters in the string representation. base 64 string has only 28 charterers!!!